# makefile set environment variables in window

Tags: windows, makefile, environment-variables

I write a makefile to set a environment variables in windows,but it does not work.
like this

```
local:
    set CONFIGOR_ENV=local
    echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
```

then i exec it,it print

```
set CONFIGOR_ENV=local
echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
ECHO 处于关闭状态。
```

then i got it
**It's not possible for a makefile to set up your environment. A makefile runs commands in a separate instance of a shell. Just like if you have two cmd.exe windows open and you set a variable in one of them, it's not set in the other one. That's the same way make works. **

so i update it,

```
local:
    set CONFIGOR_ENV=local ^
    echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
```

but it print the same massage

```
set CONFIGOR_ENV=local ^
echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
ECHO 处于关闭状态。
```

i also try the oneshell

```
.ONESHELL:
local:
    set CONFIGOR_ENV=local ^
    echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
```

print:

```
set CONFIGOR_ENV=local ^
echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
ECHO 处于关闭状态。
```

make version:

```
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I want to know that can makefile set enviranment variables in windows?

Comment: You could try declare it as a make variable and export it, like `export CONFIGOR_ENV := local`. See details in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion

Comment: Version 3.82.90 means you're using a pre-release version, not an officially released version.  That's a bad idea.  I don't think it's related to your problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `^` here.  That escapes a character: it doesn't seem like it's useful in this context.

You can either write:

```
local:
        set CONFIGOR_ENV=local & echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
```

(in Windows batch files, `&` is a command separator sort of like `;` in POSIX shell) or you can use `.ONESHELL`, if your version of make supports it, but you should remove the `^`; by adding `^` you simply escape the newline so the entire thing is assigned to the variable; that is, you're running:

```
set CONFIGOR_ENV=local  echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
```

so after this the value of the `CONFIGOR_ENV` variable will be `local  echo`.

Comment: I just try this method,but it print                                                                                              `set CONFIGOR_ENV=local & echo %CONFIGOR_ENV%
ECHO 处于关闭状态。`

Comment: This is a "feature" of the Windows shell, `cmd.exe`.  If you run two commands in the same command line they are both expanded before either is invoked.  From your Windows shell prompt run: `set FOO=bar` then at the next prompt run `set FOO=foo & echo %FOO%` and you'll see it shows `bar` (the old setting) not `foo` (the new setting).  In POSIX shell, each command is expanded individually before the next one.  I don't use Windows so I don't know how to help you solve this problem: it will require someone who knows Windows `cmd.exe` tricks.

Comment: If you don't need this value to be set only for this one command, you could add `export CONFIGOR_ENV = local` to your makefile (not in a recipe) and then it will be set for all commands that make invokes.

Comment: thanks.finally,I solve this problem by set the `export CONFIGOR_ENV=local`.With your help,i have a deep understand with the Window cmd.exe.